# Response header: Pragma: No-cache

Tags: caching, iis-7.5

So I've been fiddling around with this for quite a bit now and don't seem to be anywhere near the answer to my problem.

For some reason **IE** does not cache the static content of my website (img/js) yet **Chrome** does.

Looking at the headers I found the both the `pragma` tag, as well as the `Cache-control` have a **no-cache** set but I do not know where this thing comes from. No-where in the application the `no-cache` is ever set.

I am using `IIS 7.5` and `Oracle WebGate` as authenticator.
On our IIS itself, I have set the settings to cache the content and live for 36 hours.

Also in the `web.config` the following tag is present in the image folder:

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
        <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="30.00:00:00" />
    </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

Furthermore, I also have a tag in my `web.config` of my front-end

```
<caching>
  <cache disableExpiration="false" />
</caching>
```

I read on some forums that removing this would help but alas, it doesn't.

I also looked for `add extension` because that also seemed to be causing issues according to someone else but I never set something like that.

Has anybody got any idea what this could be causing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Oracle Web Gate uses by default cache control no-cache and pragma no-cache.
see the doc here : http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E22203_01/doc.31/e20664/chapter_12.htm
at the bottom of the page